# How does a composable component know when the value of a state has changed?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The interface that is mostly used in Jetpack Compose tutorials is the `MutableState<T>`. Its [source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/runtime/runtime/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/SnapshotState.kt?q=file:androidx%2Fcompose%2Fruntime%2FSnapshotState.kt%20class:androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState) reveals that it's an interface and it looks like this:

```
interface MutableState<T> : State<T> {
    override var value: T
    operator fun component1(): T
    operator fun component2(): (T) -> Unit
}
```

This is what the function [`mutableStateOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableStateOf(kotlin.Any,androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotMutationPolicy)) returns in such examples as:

```
val count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
```

Its parent type `State<T>` on the other hand like this:

```
interface State<out T> {
    val value: T
}
```

Seeing this I wonder how a composable knows that the `value` has changed if there are no APIs that can be subsribed to?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but it's something like it compares the old value with the new value if there not equal it triggers recomposition

Comment: @AymanAit mhmm I'm not sure about it as that doesn't sound right or efficient. I believe there must be somewhere some observable that they are listening to that takes care of comparing the new and old values and firing when they change thus triggering recomposition. I don't think composables are checking the value themselves. What I don't understand is how? All you give them is the `MutableState<T>` that has no means to be observed and yet they react to its changes.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but I suspect we don't see the whole API. Compose exposes only what's needed for the end-user, but underneath it downcasts to some internal classes. If looking into the implementation in the source code, we can see a lot of references to "snapshot" and these classes are much more complicated than the above interfaces.

Comment: Can we just call it "compiler magic"? Compose relies heavily on its compiler plugin that generates a lot of behavior that you cannot see in your source code.

Answer (score 1):

`State`, and `MutableState` are observables. When a `MutableState` changes in a Composable, that is the same as the input parameters changing to a regular Composable.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text("Hello $name")
}
```

When `name` changes that [triggers recompostion](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model). In the same way, if a mutableState variable was passed in, and it changed, that would trigger recomposition.

A question then is how does MutableState, as on observable work? That is really an interesting question, but similar to "How does a TextView make text actually show up on the screen?" It is great to dive into for academic reasons, but when trying to build stuff a lot of apis have to be treated as black boxes. Important to now what they do, not how they work.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean! They write these interfaces are observable and yet there's nothing that would suggest that and you as a developer cannot subscribe to their changes. I think @Tenfour04 is right about the compiler making observables out of them.

Answer (score 1):

It's explained in [Under the hood of Jetpack Compose — part 2 of 2](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/under-the-hood-of-jetpack-compose-part-2-of-2-37b2c20c6cdd) by Leland Richardson as

To explain how recomposition works, let’s go back to the counter example.

```
fun Counter($composer: Composer) {
 $composer.start(123)
 var count = remember($composer) { mutableStateOf(0) }
 Button(
   $composer,
   text="Count: ${count.value}",
   onPress={ count.value += 1 },
 )
 $composer.end()
}
```

> The generated code the compiler creates for this counter has a
> composer.start and compose.end. Whenever Counter executes, the runtime
> understands that when it calls count.value, it’s reading the property
> of an appmodel instance. At runtime, whenever we call compose.end, we
> optionally return a value.

```
$composer.end()?.updateScope { nextComposer ->
 Counter(nextComposer)
}
```

> Then we can call an updateScope method on that value with a lambda
> that tells the runtime how to restart this Composable, if it needs to.
> This is equivalent to the lambda that LiveData would otherwise
> receive. The reason that the question mark is here — the reason that
> this is nullable — is because, if we don’t read any model objects
> during the execution of Counter there’s no reason to teach the runtime
> how to update this because we know it never will update.

And since Recomposer is how it tracks changes, contains slot table and other composition properties i **guess** it's stored in

```
private val compositionInvalidations = mutableListOf<ControlledComposition>()
```

and recomposition happens inside Recomposer's `runRecomposeConcurrentlyAndApplyChanges` function

https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/runtime/runtime/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/Recomposer.kt;l=209